# I can't see prices in cart without login in

Tags: magento2, price

Currently I can't see product price until log in.
I checked CNS, under static block, and found this formula;

> **`<a href="{{config path='web/secure/base_url'}}customer/account/login/">Login to see the price</a>.`**

I disabled this block, deleted but still prices are not visible in cart.
Also **"Minimum Advertised Price"** is set **"NO"** in **sales configuration>sales.**

[packagingsquare.com.au](http://packagingsquare.com.au)

Comment: are you using any custom module for price hiding if yes then please disable it you will be able to see the prices of the products.